# font-face with custom font displayed "creepy"

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I've added a custom font to my project using `font-face` along with `font-family` in this way:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Caprice";
  src: url("../fonts/Caprice.ttf") format("truetype");
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Caprice", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

But the result is that the font, instead of being rendered as it should, it's being rendered in a very very "creepy way". Here's an image to let you better understand:

[image]

I've tried changing font but the result is neatly the same. I've also tried the page in different browsers without any success.

What am I doing wrong?

All the fonts I've tried are totally different from what I'm seeing displayed.

Comment: how it should look like? the font you are using is [Caprice](https://www.1001fonts.com/caprice-font.html#character-map) and it looks like how it should look like.

Comment: This looks like it's doing exactly like what your CSS says it should be doing. What's the actual problem? IF you think it doesn't look right, you probably want to show what you think it _should_ look like, with some text to explain why you think that should be the correct look.

Comment: After few days I managed to figure it out. I was refactoring some stuff and accidentally I inverted the name on two fonts. There's nothing wrong with the CSS.